# Using Google Earth Engine in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: google-earth-engine, arcgis-pro

I have been trying ways to use GEE in ArcGIS Pro but it keeps giving errors. So when I clone an environment and give it a name and activate it. Now I open a newscript and type the following code

```py
import ee
import geemap
```

These steps are fine. After this I try this code

```
ee.Initialize()
```

It never works. I have even authenticated GEE using command prompt several times.

```
EEException                               Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [12]:
Line 1:     ee.Initialize()

File C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\gee\lib\site-packages\ee\__init__.py, in Initialize:
Line 140:   ApiFunction.initialize()

File C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\gee\lib\site-packages\ee\apifunction.py, in initialize:
Line 154:   signatures = data.getAlgorithms()

File C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\gee\lib\site-packages\ee\data.py, in getAlgorithms:
Line 1317:  return _cloud_api_utils.convert_algorithms(_execute_cloud_call(call))

File C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\gee\lib\site-packages\ee\data.py, in _execute_cloud_call:
Line 347:   raise _translate_cloud_exception(e)

EEException: Not signed up for Earth Engine or project is not registered. Visit https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/access
```

I don't know much programming.

Can somebody explain how to fix this issue?

I just want to use ArcGIS Pro to perform calculations in GEE.

Comment: Which version of Arcgis Pro are you using?

Comment: Are you trying to run your code in ArcGIS Pro’s Python Window, an ArcGIS Notebook or somewhere else?